# Thread creation after mce_loop

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'd like to combine an `mce_loop` with threads created by `threads->create`, but fail. The simplified script below never reaches the second print line. Why?

(It works if I create the threads first, but in my real script this would make other parts more complicated).

```
use MCE::Loop;

mce_loop { } (0);
print "OK\n";

threads->create (sub {});
print "never reached ..\n";
```

Comment: Did you forget `use threads; use threads::shared;` ? According to the [manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MCE/lib/MCE/Core.pod) it should come before `use MCE::Loop`.

Comment: I tried this of course, but It doesn't change the behaviour. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the (later deleted) example posted by Håkon Hægland I figured out what really helps in my simplified example. I still don't get the reason for this strange behaviour.

```
use MCE::Loop;

mce_loop { } (0);
MCE->new ()->run; # this, but why?
print "OK\n";

threads->create (sub {});
print "never reached ..\n";
```